# Django: Getting an error that SignUpForm has no attribute clean_data

Tags: python, django, forms, models

here is the stuff. i'm not exactly sure what part is going wrong. please help me out! :) i am a littl ebit confused hahaha

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'First Name','required':True}))
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Last Name','required':True}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Email','required':True}))
    emailConfirm = forms.EmailField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Confirm email','required':True}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=256, label="", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    datetime = forms.DateTimeInput()
    class Meta:
        model=SignUp
        fields=['fname','lname','email','password',]

    def clean_fname(self):
        name = self.clean_data.get('fname')
        if ' ' in name:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please do not have a space in your name.")
        else:
            return name
```

Comment: Isn't it exactly what the error tells you? The class SignUpForm does not have an attribute called clean_data. Yet the code is trying to access it?

Answer (score 6):

That's right there's no attribute `clean_data` perhaps `cleaned_data` will help you...

Answer (score 1):

`clean_data` was used in the previous django versions instead use `cleaned_data`
and your problem will be solved